# Date into array with implode and stropos

Tags: php, date

i have a date input javascript that lets users add as many dates onto the database at once, this is using implode and stores as one big string like 2015-01-01 2015-01-02 etc...

I also want this to find out if one of those days contains a weekend day. I have no idea how the string and date parameters meet with this.

```
$week_end_check = array();    

$week_end_check = implode(' ',date('D'), strtotime($_POST['dates']));

    if ((strpos($week_end_check,'Sun')) || (strpos($week_end_check,'Sat' ))) {
        $weekend = '1';
    }
```

the above wont work as I know but can somebody help me...you can understand what i am after by the above i hope.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a less contrived way to do this:

```
$weekend = false;
foreach($_POST['dates'] as $date) {
    $day = (new DateTime($date))->format('D');
    if (in_array($day, array('Sun', 'Sat'))) {
         $weekend = true;
         break;
    }
}
```

1. Set `$weekend` to `false` by default
2. Loop through each date
3. Get the day of the week
4. Check to see if it "Sun" or "Sat"
5. Set `$weekend` to `true`
6. End the loop once we know a weekend day has been found

Comment: thanks @john i have never seen the break function before (sorry), very handy indeed. the break will save me a few other headaches i have, thank you sir!

Answer (score 1):

Please use this example. .

```
$string = "2015-01-01 2015-01-02 2015-01-04 2015-01-06";

$array = explode(" ",$string);

$weekend_array = array();

$total = count($array);

for($i=0;$i<$count;$i++)
{
       $my_day = date("D", strtotime($array[$i]));

       if($my_day=="Sun" || $my_day=="Sat")
       {
               $weekend_array[] = $array[$i];
       }

}

echo "<pre>";
    print_r($weekend_array);
echo "<pre>";
```

Comment: thank you Anil, the above answer is a shorter way of doing it but i appreciate yours worked for me too, thanks.